# C++ strtoull function undefined?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using visual studio 2012 and `strtoull` is undefined while `strtoul` works OK. I have included

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

But `strtoull` is still undefined.

Comment: Do you have a C99 compiler? Also, you may benefit from adding the C tag. In C++, you get `std::stroull` from `<cstdlib>`, but only since C++11.

Comment: Try [searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320173.aspx), and you will see that VS 2013 has it, but not earlier versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some versions of MSVC don't have a `strtoull` function.

You can try using `_strtoui64`.

**Edit:**

Like mentioned in the comments you can also try switching to C++11 if it is available to you.

Comment: It *does* exist in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why those guys force me to use _strtoui64? I mean, I am 99+% sure g++ doesn't know what `_strtoui64` is, right?

Comment: If I wanted to copy the source code from VS13 to my project because VS12 doesn't support this, is this legal? Also, where the source code of the function is located, I can only find this: `_Check_return_ _CRTIMP unsigned long long __cdecl strtoull(_In_z_ const char * _Str, _Out_opt_ _Deref_post_z_ char ** _EndPtr, _In_ int _Radix);`

Comment: thanks @Lightness_Races_in_Orbit, I corrected my answer.

Comment: @luka I'm fairly sure that's a reference to a function implemented in a dll somewhere. If you don't link against the VS13 c++ runtime, you won't be able to resolve that function. So copying it won't do anything useful.

Comment: @black He is going the other way around (string to number, not number to string).

Comment: @Luka G++ almost certainly doesn't know about `_strtoui64`.  But Microsoft has never supported C99, and `long long` (and `strtoull`) weren't part of C++ until 2011.  The usual way of handling this is with conditionally defined macros: `#ifdef _WIN32|#define StrToULL _strtoui64|#else|#define StrToULL strtoull|#endif` (but with line breaks instead of the `|`).  Then use `StrToULL` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle it (that is portable, does not require Boost, and works in C++03):

```
std::string s = SOME_NUMER_IN_A_STRING_FORMAT;
unsigned long myValue = 0;
std::istringstream iss(s);
if (!(iss >> myValue))
{
    // error parsing number
}
else
{
    // myValue successfully parsed
}
```

Note that if you want a 64-bit integer in a pre-C++11 compiler, you'll have to use a compiler-specific type (which may not have an overload for stream operations).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Boost Lexical Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) as it is more portable. I think it utilizes `operator<<` and `operator>>` to manage most conversions.

`boost::lexical_cast<unsigned long long>( aString );` or so

Comment: The problem is that `boost::lexical_cast` doesn't provide nearly the same functionality.  And is probably significantly slower, since it probably calls `strtoull` somewhere under the hood (in `std::ostringstream`, for example).

Comment: @JamesKanze Did you mean `std::istringstream`?  I don't see why it would use an output stream when converting from a string.

Comment: @James I'm with you on the lack of functionality, but it is most definitely **not** slower, [quite the contrary is true](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html)

Comment: @JamesKanze Well, he didn't say if he needed alternate base conversion. If he does, then I'd probably use `istringstream` and `hex` or whatever. It's more portable than any compiler built-in.

Comment: @ZacHowland Yes.  `boost::lexical_cast` actually uses both, at least in the generic case, but it's `std::istringstream` (or rather `std::num_get<char>`, which it calls) which will use `std::strtoull` (or if not, something with similar functionality).

Comment: @rubenvb I can't find any comparisons with `stdtoull` on that page.  Only comparisons with functions which have to parse extra format information.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG `strtoull` isn't a "compiler built-in"; it's part of the standard C library, and also the standard C++ library since C++11.

Comment: @James you are correct. Would be an interesting extra point of comparison, because indeed a scanf/printf comparison could potentially increase extra overhead (although I'd expect string literals with just one argument to be optimized as compiler builtins, especially with GCC).

Comment: @JamesKanze Apparently not in asker's version of VS. The accepted answer is to use `_strtoui64`, which is a built-in. Hence my assertion that `lexical_cast` (or `istringstream`) is more portable.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG `_strtoui64` isn't a "build-in" either; it's a library function.  And I'm not sure that `istringstream` is more portable; I know that I've used systems where there was no `<<` for `long long` and `unsigned long long`.  (Pre C++11 didn't have `long long` either.)  Using a system dependent macro to give `stdtoull` or `_strtoui64` is probably the most portable you can get.